# Checking List within String (python)

Tags: python, if-statement

I know you can check if a word matches a word list

```
fruit = 'bananas'
fruitList = ('apples', 'bananas', 'cherries')

if fruit in fruitList:
  do something
```

Is there a similar way to do it backwards? To find if a word in a list is contained in a string?

```
fruitString = 'I like bananas'
fruitList = ('apples', 'bananas', 'cherries')

if fruitList in fruitString:
  do something
```

I know I can check using a loop:

```
for fruit in fruitList:
  if fruit in fruitString:
    do something
```

But I was wondering if there was a cool one-line pythonic comparison. I've tried something like `any(f in fruitList for f in fruitString)` but my python-fu is weak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt with [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) was very close, you just had your inputs flipped:

```
if any(fruit in fruitString for fruit in fruitList):
  # do something
```